# Replacing ManyToMany relationship in django

Tags: django

How can I replace ManyToMany relationship in django with something else .
I heard about multiple select field or multiple choice field module that we can install it with pip.
Is it true?
If it is true how can I use it?

And if there are other ways can you tell me?

```
Class Post(models.Model):
   Title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
Class Category(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: can you explain bit more about what you want to do and what are you facing ?

Comment: Look I want to join Post and Category that they have manytomany relationship but i dont want to use ManyToMany . i want to know is that other way to join them without it?

Comment: But _why_ don't you want to use `ManyToManyField`? The UI widget (as you allude to in the post) isn't tightly coupled to the underlying field type.

Comment: In general, when asking a question, try to sketch the problem and the end result you're trying to achieve, rather than ask for a specific technical solution. Because it's impossible for us to give an answer if we don't know the exact issue you're facing or what you're trying to achieve. You already decided on a route ("replace ManyToMany relationship") but it doesn't make sense if you want to join Post to Category to not have a many-to-many relationship. If you are specific about what you want to achieve maybe we can come up with a different route.

Comment: If you do not want to use many_to_many field then you have to query them separately and get data from both class and can save data in another class or can use data to get your results.